# Bootstrap 5 tooltip arrow missing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am using Bootstrap 5 tooltip. It is working just fine, but the tooltip arrow is missing. The tooltip is displayed more like a block.

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({'placement': 'bottom'});
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</a>
        
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

PS: When I change to bootstrap version 4, the arrow shows. But for my project, I need to use Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Bootstrap 4

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Use this instead it will work:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but I need to keep version 4 for the js file and version 5 for the css. Any possible workaround?